# Will playing offline affect trophy acquisition?

Tags: psn, demons-souls

I'm picking up *Demon's Souls* again so I can play through it before the servers close. However, while trying to plan for a trophy run and somewhat efficient playthrough, everything I've read recommends playing in offline mode in order to make it easier to get Perfect White/Black World Tendencies.

If I play offline, will I still be able to get the trophies? I'm wondering how exactly this works if I need to be signed out of PSN in order to play offline. If I don't get them while playing offline, it partially negates trying to go for an optimized run in the first place...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've [checked](http://www.ps3trophies.org/forum/general-ps3-discussion/2241-can-i-get-trophies-offline.html) [out](http://forums.demonssouls.info/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=8341) [a few](http://www.gamespot.com/forums/topic/26663738) [sources](http://forums.gametrailers.com/thread/if-you-earn-trophies-offline--/1208000), and it looks like it is possible to acquire PSN trophies while offline. They just don't sync up to your online profile until the next time you sign-on.

Comment: This is crorrect.

Comment: How does this work with multiple profiles on one machine? If my boyfriend were to sign on first after I'd played, would they sync to his profile instead (I'd *kill* him...)?

Comment: No, each profile will need to be synced separately in order for all trophies to register. Syncing one profile does not affect the other

Comment: @FAE I only have one profile on my console, so I'm not sure, but don't you still need to play as a profile offline (you just don't sign in)?