# Is it possible to complete Demon's Souls 100% if I play offline?

Tags: achievements, demons-souls

[Atlus will be taking down down the *Demon's Souls* servers (North American ones, at least) on May 31st](http://www.vg247.com/2012/04/11/north-american-servers-for-demons-souls-shutting-down-may-31/).

I haven't got around to finishing *Demon's Souls* yet but I want to achieve a Platinum trophy in the game. Will it be possible/feasible once the servers are offline? How will that affect me?

Comment: I wish to you sir, a good luck.

Comment: Atlas has decided to extend the servers beyond May 31st. Yay!

Comment: I'm assuming you meant **Atlus** :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will playing offline affect trophy acquisition?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/57256/will-playing-offline-affect-trophy-acquisition)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is certainly possible.

None of the Trophies for Demon's Souls are based around online features of the game.

PS3Trophies.Org [has a list of the trophies and information on how to achieve them](http://www.ps3trophies.org/game/demons-souls/guide/) which corroborates this.

Answer (score 4):

It is actually easier to get all achievements when playing offline the whole time because online play tends to screw with your world tendency.

Answer (score 0):

In **PS5's Demon's Souls Remake** you cannot get all 100% achievements offline.

These achievements require online interactions:

- **Return to Form**

> Help a player vanquish a boss

- **Unwelcome Guest**

> Vanquish a player as an invader

Answer (score -1):

Oddly enuff my reply from the customer support about asking this just came in as I was reading this .

No it won't affect it at all it's still quite possible ,app' the whole souls series they look at  how the game could still be played fully offline in years to come, which is nice ,obviously it won be the same exp but still hell of a game.

An good example (although not same team or even atlus) but in ds2 you find a token of spite and a token of fidelity in game and they are both as you know online play items but they are still in the game offline ,I wish more companys Thoyght about this instead of large areas of games now being totally unplayable (and many of those still have servers lol)

Enjoy your playthrough and I hope you get your platinum soon.

Comment: I am wondering why this was made as a Community Wiki